# ¿Cómo modificar un plugin en Moodle para eliminar un encabezado generado por PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, moodle

Estoy intentado quitar el título de: "Mosaico 1" generado por el código php y javascript de un plugin en Moodle cual edita formatos de cursos.

El problema es que no encuentro el fichero que genera ese encabezado html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Aunque traduzcas tu pregunta, debes mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Por otra parte, puedes hacer la pregunta en [wordpress.se] (en inglés).

Comment: Ya que no lo encuentras y aquí no ayudamos sin un [example] que no proporcionas en la pregunta (el enlace al plugin no vale, las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas) ¿no puedes esconderlo con CSS directamente?

Comment: Incluso podías decir qué plugin es, al menos, ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, aplicando lo que te comente, encontré la clase en un solo archivo template, no podría asegurarte si comentándolo funciona pero encontré la ruta, prueba y verifica si desaparece o no.

La ruta es esta: `moodle-format_tiles > templates > multi_section_tile.mustache`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero resuelva tu inconveniente

Comment: Gracias por el consejo @Gabriel, aunque he buscado el parámetro pero solo me salen ficheros CSS cuáles eliminando la regla no hacen desaparecer el título. El problema está en que no logro localizar el fichero que genera ese html.

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con una posible solución, verifica si es correcta!

Comment: Comentando no funciona, pero eliminando sí. Te debo una, mañana entro para valorar tu respuesta. ¡MUCHA SUERTE CON TU PÁGINA WEB :D!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado! Gracias e igualmente!